# Spark doesn't download dependencies from mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.35

Tags: apache-spark

I'm specifying the following and I still get a class not found exception.

```
spark.jars.packages=mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.35
```

Any idea what could be happening?

Answer (score -1):

Correct syntax for `conf/spark-defaults.conf` doesn't include `=`:

```
spark.jars.packages mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.35
```

Comment: Okay. I wasn't using spark-defaults.conf I was using a SparkConf object